# Sum of a series using a for loop in C++

Tags: c++

I want to compute the sum of the following series:

```
5 + 8 + 11 + .... + 50
```

I wish to use a for loop to print the above series and the sum of the series. I have written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, sum = 0, n = 50;
    cout << "\n\n THE SERIES IS UNDER : \n\n\n";
    i = 2;
    while(i <= n)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
        if (i == 2)
            cout << i;
        else
            cout << " + "<< i;
        i = i + 3;
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n THE SUMMATION IS "<< sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your question is? What result would you expect? What result do you actually get?

Comment: What is the series ? Its not an AP and to determine whether its a GP or HP, you need atleast 4 consecutive terms.

Comment: Also, the expression `cout<<" + ",i` does not do what you think it does, read about [the comma expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: The sequence should be ``5+8+...``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "\n\n THE SERIES IS UNDER : \n\n\n";

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 5; i < 50; i += 3) {
        cout << i << '+';
        sum += i;
    }
    cout << 50 << endl;
    sum += 50;

    cout << "\n\n\n THE SUMMATION IS " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Changes in this version:

1. Include `iostream` instead of `iostream.h`; [this is more portable between compilers](http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html)
2. Using a  `for` loop here is more concise and clear.
3. The test `if (i == 2)  cout << i;` is a waste of time because it's true for only one iteration. Instead you can handle the first item or the last item as a special case outside of the `for` loop.
4. Use `sum += i` instead of `sum = sum + i`, since the former is more clear and efficient.  Most programmers will choose the former one by default.
5. Generally you want to use `cout << endl` in C++. There is a difference between `'\n'` and `endl`, unless you have a reason not to do so. See the post: [C++: "std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

Comment: You've changed a few different things at once here; this answer could be improved by adding a little commentary about what you changed and why, so the original requester can learn from each of these changes.

Comment: Sure, that's fine. I didn't intentionally remove it, our edits just collided. Sorry. To avoid the same happening again, I'll leave further edits up to you.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks for your wording :)

Answer (score 4):

```
cout<<"\n\n\n THE SUMMATION IS ",sum;
```

->

```
cout << "\n\n\n THE SUMMATION IS " << sum;
```

and

```
cout<<" + ",i;
```

->

```
cout << " + " << i;
```

The comma (`,`) operator does not work here like the stream (`<<`) operator.

Comment: I seem to have gotten a downvote here. Is there a problem with my answer? Are those `->` ugly or something? :s

Comment: It appears they changed their code.

Comment: Oh God. Was that really necessary?

Comment: @user123 Your answer was very helpful. Thank you :)